# how to fix Memory leak array on AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

How can I solve the leak that happened in the sample code below, as seen in this image:   [image]

```
import UIKit

import Alamofire

import AlamofireObjectMapper

class ViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    load { (posts: [Post]) in
        posts.map({ (post: Post) -> Void in
            print(post.title)
        })
    }
 }


 func load( posts: (([Post]) -> Void)!) {
    let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    let url = try! urlString.asURL()
    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Post]>) in
        guard let postArray = response.result.value else {return}
        posts(postArray)
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, are you able to identify any solution yet?

Comment: @iDevAmit What I did was follow the documentation of Alamofire about ResponseCollectionSerializable. Works fine for me. Also I create a sample project for testing, if you wanna take a look. https://github.com/FashionFrau/AlamofireCollection

Comment: Thanks, I will try with same.